# Call a method on change of a value

Tags: java, multithreading

There is a variable called age,

```
int static age = 21;
```

I want to call method

```
onAgeIncreased(){
    ........... something......
}
```

whenever the age is changed by any thread in my program (Just like in event driven programming). Can I get it done with java?

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [Observer](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternObserver/article.html) pattern. Here's a tutorial for Java.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the variable via a setter method and do stuff there.

Comment: this is a comment just saying

Comment: To be an answer length is not a concern But the content.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in `Java`. You can use getter and setter.

```
public class MyTest{
 private static int age = 21;

 public void setAge(int age){
   this.age=age;
 }

 public int getAge(){
   return  age;
 }
}
```

When ever you want to change the `age`, you can use `setAge(int newAge)` method to change `age`, Then when ever you want to get `age` back just call `getAge()`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by sticking to *JavaBeans* convention and implement `PropertyChangeListener` that be listening whenever the value changed. You can also utilize `PropertyChangeSupport` that is thread safe. [Withing a Javadoc of it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html) you can find a very nice example that will suits your needs.